# Reuse a custom inflated view similar to convertView in a ListView

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm currently working on an app that contains a timetable screen, which is built in a highly customised way and contains a lot of 'repeated' views.

I've got each individual view that I need (eg, a view for a box that contains the title of an event and the time that it's on) set up in XML, which I inflate in a custom view class. For example:

```
public class EventCell extends RelativeLayout {
    private TextView eventTitle;
    private TextView eventTime;
    private Button favouritesButton;

    public EventCell(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setupView(context);
    }

    public EventCell(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setupView(context);
    }

    private void setupView(Context context) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.timetable_event, this);

        eventTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.event_title);
        eventTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.event_time);
        favouritesButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.favourites_button);   
    }
    ...
}
```

This is fine except for the fact that this view is reused quite a lot in its containing activity. Eg, it might be instantiated 50 times. My problem is that this wastes a lot of memory and causes some devices to crash.

In ListViews, there's the getView() method which gives an a convertView parameter that lets you check if the current row has already been instantiated, and then lets you update the values on that. What I'm after is a similar thing for this custom view; ideally reusing it rather than instantiating it a bunch of times.

If there isn't a way, what's the best method of getting around it? The views themselves aren't particularly complicated but still manage to bring the most devices to their knees it seems.